# What does projective space $\mathbf{S}^{2 N-1} / U(1) \cong \mathbf{C} \mathbf{P}^{N-1}$ mean?

Tags: momentum, gauge-theory, group-theory, hamiltonian-formalism

In David Tong's [lecture notes on Gauge Theory](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/gaugetheory.html), in the section on 'Quantising the Colour Degree of Freedom', the following statement is confusing me,

> Since we already have the constraint (2.16), this means that the vectors parameterise the projective space $
> \mathbf{S}^{2 N-1} / U(1) \cong \mathbf{C} \mathbf{P}^{N-1}
> $.

There's a later statement that I'm also not getting,

> This means that the momentum conjugate to $w$ is $iw^\dagger$ and, correspondingly, $\mathrm{CP}^{N-1}$

I haven't given more detail in this question because I'm really just looking to first understand this projective space notation and it's meaning, before tackling how Tong is using it in this context.

Comment: Do you not understand how the two spaces are isomorphic or do you not understand what spaces are meant by this notation?

Comment: Both really. The answer from @spiridon_the_sun_rotator explained the latter to me, but I'm still looking around to understand why they are isomorphic.

Answer (score 2):

1. Concerning the first question, Tong imposes the following constraint on the $N$-dimensional complex vector $w$:
   $$
   w^{\dagger} w = \kappa
   $$
   The manifold, defined by this constraint, is the sphere in $R^{2 N}$ space or simply $S^{2N-1}$. Then from the action, one sees, that there is a gauge symmetry - multiplication by an arbitrary phase, which can be interpreted as rotation along a chosen axis. Because all points, which are related by such a rotation are identified - the actual manifold, $w$ defines is a quotient:
   $$
   S^{2n-1}/U(1)
   $$
   The CP^{N-1} is defined as $C^{N} / C^{*}$. The identification by a phase, and multiplication by an arbitrary radius $\sqrt{\kappa} \neq 0$ - makes an arbitrary complex number $\neq 0$.

2. The action *2.17* is linear in derivative $\frac{dw}{dt}$. The Lagrangian has the form
   $p \dot{q} - H(q, p)$. Therefore, one immediately infers, that:
   $$
   p = i w^{\dagger}
   $$

Comment: I'm not familiar with the $CP^{N-1} = C^N/C^*$ fact. In particular, why is it $C^*$? Can you point me to a reference with a physics-oriented perspective, if you know of one?

Comment: Regarding (2), why is $CP^{N-1}$ the phase space of the system rather than the configuration space?

Comment: Concerning the $C^{*}$ - we exclude zero, because multiplication by zero identifies any point in any space. As for physics friendly introduction to these concepts, I recommend Nakahara's book - "Geometry and Topology for physicts", where are all core concepts, required to work with the modern theoretical physics are presented in a user-friendly manner. Concerning the difference between the configuration space and the phase space - in the simple sitatuation - phase space is defined by cotangent bundle to the configuration manifold $T^{*} M$.

Comment: However, in this case the momentum $i w^{\dagger}$ belongs to the same space as $w$